# Cannot make max-width work with Bootstrap dropdown-menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu. The menu items can be quite large in some cases. So I need to set a `max-width`. In addition, I don't want the menu items to be cut so I must use `white-space: normal` too. The problem is that my `max-width` is completely ignored. If I set `width` instead it does work. But I do not want that as I may have menus where the whole menu would fix in much less space than `width`. That's why I need `max-width` to work rather than `width`.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvwz5omq/) illustrates the problem. As you can see, the menu items are not expanded up to 400px.

[UPDATE]
Ok, I was clearly missing the `position: relative`. That fixes the menu of the first case which I tried to isolate as much as possible. My code actually relies on [this Bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3). In that example, `position: relative` breaks such a cascade submenu.

Any ideas how can then make such a cascade menu with my contrains?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add the following:

```
  width: 100%
  max-width: 400px;
```

Your element needs a certain width so that max-width works

http://jsfiddle.net/dvwz5omq/1/

Comment: ...and add position: relative;

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the value of the `min-width` property because it is set to 160px;

```
.dropdown-menu {
  max-width: 100px;
  min-width: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override the `position: absolute;` style from `.dropdown-menu` with `position: relative;`.

> By default the dropmenu has been position absolute to its parent
>   element. It will take the same width if given the style `width: 100%`.
>   since it has some `min-width` which make it to exceed its parent
>   width. Therefore we have to make the dropmenu independent of its
>   parent element width.

I hope it will helps you